# User account password removed but terminal still asking for password

Tags: updates, password, gnome-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Authenticate user that has no password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73882/authenticate-user-that-has-no-password)

I'm new to Ubuntu. I recently installed 11.10 and removed the user account password. However, now when I try to do anything in terminal, it always ask for password even though I don't have a password set. I cannot perform any "sudo" commands without entering a password. I've try to press ENTER without typing anything for the password and I get "Sorry, try again." Any advise will be appreciated.