# Password authentication problem

Tags: 12.04, password, authentication

So I wanted to download some software, and it says I need to put in my password, but I didn't put a password on my account, so I didn't add a password and clicked authenticate, but it says that my authentication attempt was unsuccessful, what do I do? I can't download anything now... and i'm new to ubuntu as well...

Comment: wait never mind i just found the answer... if you have the same problem, here's the link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150181/cannot-authenticate-without-a-password

the first answer that tells you to go into terminal is the right one